# how-to-connect-blockchain-node-over-cloud?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, nodes, cloud-mining

I am creating a one private blockchain network over aws cloud with the help of 2 ubuntu instances. But I am unable to connect 2 nodes. Even I have checked it with ping with its internal Ips and both are working perfectly.

I have follow below command to do that,

sudo geth --datadir="ethdata" --verbosity 10 --ipcdisable --port 30303 --networkid 15 nodiscover console --allow-insecure-unlock --unlock "public address" --password password --http --http.port "8000" --http.addr "0.0.0.0" –http.corsdomain "*" --http.api "eth,net,web3,miner,debug,personal,rpc"

admin.addPeer("enode://7ac1...2337f8@xxx:xxx:xx:xxx:30303?discport=0")

Same Setup I have tried it over 2 different local system where I am able to connect it successfully.

Do anyone know about this ? is there any problem with ports over cloud or something else ? I have also tried it with different ports and network ids but could not able to connect it.

Comment: Does anything related to the connection appear in the output? Using sudo to run any server is generally not a good idea.

Comment: I have tried without sudo as well. It shows an error of "Dial error conn=staticdial err="i/o timeout" eth node:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to resolve this issue by adding ports into my security group over cloud.
Before, I had added only one port 8000 into the security group, but face the same problem. After that I have added all the mentioned ports that I have used (8000 and 30303) for both nodes. As a result I am able to connect it blockchain node. Also tested with mining where blocks are synchronizing.